# Why won't this work comparing a variable in PHP?

Tags: php

I could use `in_array` but I tried this instead,

```
$_POST['stat'] == ('strength' || 'speed' || 'agility' || 'endurance')
```

The reason being is I decided to turn on `E_ALL`, my original `if` being,

```
if (isset($_GET['workout'], $_POST['stat']) && $_POST['stat'] == 'strength' || $_POST['stat'] == 'speed' || $_POST['stat'] == 'agility' || $_POST['stat'] == 'endurance')
```

But I got 3 notices for undefined variable `stat` even though I tested it with isset?

Comment: How do you receive `GET` and `POST` at the same time - `if (isset($_GET['workout'], $_POST['stat'])` ? Shouldn't it be one or another?

Comment: Why does it matter if I use `,` that is the impression of how I got to use it on php.net

Comment: @ZoltanToth: it's possible to have both `$_POST` and `$_GET` in PHP. Create a form with `action="script.php?query=string"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't "or" strings like that:

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > var_dump('a' || 'b');
bool(true)
php > var_dump('strength' || 'speed' || 'agility' || 'endurance');
bool(true);
```

You'd need to use `in_array()` for this to work:

```
if (isset($_POST['stat') && in_array($_POST['stat'], array('strength', 'speed', 'agility', 'endurance')) { 
 ...
}
```

Comment: Is it ok to use, `isset($a, $b)` or is it like `empty()`

Comment: isset can test multiple values, and only returns true if they're ALL set. evaluation stops and returns false on the first unset value.

Answer (score 1):

Because `('strength' || 'speed' || 'agility' || 'endurance')` resolves as `true` (since it is a true value or another true value or etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this instead

```
if (isset($_GET['workout'], $_POST['stat']))
{
    // Check the value after we're sure that it's set
    if ($_POST['stat'] == 'strength' || $_POST['stat'] == 'speed' || $_POST['stat'] == 'agility' || $_POST['stat'] == 'endurance')
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this is that there is a comparison || that failed to short circuit the condition

```
if (isset($_GET['workout'], $_POST['stat']) && $_POST['stat'] == 'strength' || $_POST['stat'] == 'speed' || $_POST['stat'] == 'agility' || $_POST['stat'] == 'endurance')
```

Digesting your logic, it will evaluate to if `$_POST['stat']` is not set

```
false && $_POST['stat'] == 'strength' // short circuit, thus will not evaluate 2nd condition
// then evaluates the ORs which happens to be $_POST['stat'] is not set thus the 3 notices
```